# Showing sum of non decreasing functions is non decreasing

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ are non decreasing, then $f_1 + f_2$ is non decreasing. Suppose $x < y$, then we have $f_1(x) \leq f_1(y)$ and $f_2(x) \leq f_2(y)$ and hence $f_1(x) + f_2(x) \leq f_1(y) + f_2(y)$ so the sum is increasing. By induction, we can extend this to $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i $ if $f_i$ are non decreasing.

Question: does this work for a countable number of non decreasing functions? In other words, if $\{ f_i \}_{i =1}^{\infty} $ are non decreasing functions, does it follow that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i $$

is non decreasing ?

Comment: Just use that if $S_n\leq T_n$ then $\lim_n S_n\leq\lim_n T_n$, with $S_n,T_n$ being the partial sums of the series.

Comment: If the sum is convergent, yes, as @Tom points out.